# Attachment download from view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Is there a way to list all documents in a view control (or a repeat control) and have a download button / link that will allow the user to download multiple attachments that reside in a rich text field?

I have found options using the @AttachmentName, however this lists all attachments on the document and does not restrict the attachments to just one the RTF.

I have a work around using a dialog box, which does work well, just not as clean as the option I was looking for.

Comment: What stops you from using the code you use in the dialog in a view column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a view you can have a computed column. Any code you place into a dialog could be placed into a computed column. The getDocument() method of the XSPviewEntry gives you access to the document (recycle wisely).

**update**

To use a download control, use a repeat with the view as datasource and a panel per row. The panel has the data source pointing to a document. Use tr as tag for the panel.

This is only needed if you have attachments in other fields you don't want to show

Comment: My solution using the dialog box uses the file download control bound to the rich text field when the dialog box opens.  I am not aware of any method of adding a core control to the view as rich text fields are not items that can be displayed in a notes view?

Comment: Then a repeat control it is. Use a repeat control and have a panel with a data source. Each panel turns into a row in your table.