# Is there a simple way to allow a user to download the files in selected documents from a viewPanel?

Tags: xpages

I have a portal where users sign in and see a bunch of documents sorted and categorized by year then category.  They want a check box next to each document so they can select one or many documents then press a button to download all the files from the selected documents.

There is only one file per document.

Is there an easy way to program such a thing?

Comment: The [first four links on Google](http://bfy.tw/28Le) give some pretty good information on how to do this. If you're looking to link to the _first_ attachment in a document, check out [Paul Withers' blog post on the subject](http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-open-first-attachment-in-view/). The fourth link from that Google search shows that this question may be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495491/attachment-download-from-view.

Comment: Thanks for the google help Eric.  LOL.  I was hoping to find a sample of sorts that allowed a button at the top of the view that will download a file from each of the selected documents ( using check boxes ).  I have an idea how to walk a list of selected documents ( I think ) but not sure how to call the download for each.  

I was hoping someone already did this and wouldn't mind sharing some code to I don't have to reinvent the wheel so to speak.

Comment: I'm glad it was appreciated :-P In any case, I like Knut's answer, especially as zip is the de facto standard for multiple attachments.

Answer (score 5):

You want to download attachments from selected documents all at once.

Create a **zip** file which contains all attachments and download the one zip file.

You can find the code for creating a zip file from document's attachments [in Naveen Maurya's XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=download-all-attachments).

Extend this code in a way that you run through all selected documents and grab the attachments from there.

Set a session scope variable with the the Ids of all selected documents in your XPage's button and open XPage zip.xsp (XSnippet's XAgent)

```xml
<xp:button
    id="button1"
    value="Download">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
                        sessionScope.selectedIds = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
                        }]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
                <xp:openPage name="/zip.xsp"></xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Read the Ids from session scope in zip.xsp, get the documents and their attachments and put them all in one zip file.

```js
...
var selectedIds = sessionScope.selectedIds;
for(i=0; i < selectedIds.length; i++) {
    var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(selectedIds[i]);
    var attachments:java.util.Vector = session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc);
    // Loop through all the attachments
    for (var i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
        ...
```

---

As an **alternative**, you can download all files at once with multiple `window.open(url)` on client side:

- collect all attachment's URLs on server side
- write those in a hidden input field
- execute CSJS code in onComplete event to open each URL in a separate window

This is a working example code:

```xml
<xp:button
    id="button1"
    value="Download">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="panelDownloadURLs">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var viewPanel = getComponent("viewPanel1");
            var selectedIDs = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
            var filesToDownload = "";
            for(i=0; i < selectedIDs.length; i++) {
                var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByID(selectedIDs[i]);
                var attachments:java.util.Vector = session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc);
                for (var i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                    var attachment = doc.getAttachment(attachments.get(i).toString());
                    if (attachment != null) {
                        filesToDownload += context.getUrl().getAddress().replace(view.getPageName(), '') + 
                            '/0/' + doc.getUniversalID() + '/$FILE/' + attachment.getName() + '#';
                    }
                }
            }
            getComponent("inputDownloadURLs").setValue(filesToDownload);}]]></xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[
            var filesToDownload = dojo.byId("#{id:inputDownloadURLs}").value.split("#");
            for (var i = 0; i < filesToDownload.length; i++) {
                if (!filesToDownload[i].toString() == "") {
                    window.open(filesToDownload[i]);
                }
            }]]></xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:panel
    id="panelDownloadURLs">
    <xp:inputHidden
        id="inputDownloadURLs"
        value=""></xp:inputHidden>
</xp:panel>
```

But, this alternative solution feels a bit messy if you have a lot of attachments...

Comment: That would not work. This is an auditor portal that could be downloading dozens or hundreds of files.

Comment: @Bitwyse1 You apply the same principal to a single document's attachments. It would be almost identical to what Knut has laid out, but invoked from day a button for that row's doc.

Comment: The zip solution is then perfect in your case. I added some code snippets to show how to extend the zip XSnippet.

Comment: In regard to Knut's first solution, I don't get past the first line of script on the zip.xsp. the first debug line writes to the log, but not the second.. print("TEST 01");
var downloadDocument:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(context.getUrl().getParameter("documentUNID"));
print("TEST 02");
var attachments:java.util.Vector = session.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", downloadDocument);

Comment: You could also use the HTML5 download attribute. Client side javascript to add the attribute to links to files, click them, then remove the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out.  Using a combination of the zip file code from  in [Naveen Maurya's XSnippet.](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=download-all-attachments) and some [java code found here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/).  I will post my final code once finished.

It turns out I didn't need to download attached documents rather files from the servers file system.